# udev related to Casio EX-ZR700: camera cannot be attached as disk, Debian Buster

Tags: usb, debian, camera, udev

After changing from Fedora to Debian, I'm not more able to attach via hotplug the Casio EX-ZR700 camera. I expect to see the partition of the mass storage device as usually. But there is a cycle of USB attach and detach.

```
[20558.913275] usb 6-4: new high-speed USB device number 26 using ehci-pci
[20559.071692] usb 6-4: New USB device found, idVendor=07cf, idProduct=117a, bcdDevice=10.00
[20559.071696] usb 6-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=4
[20559.071698] usb 6-4: Product: CASIO QV DIGITAL
[20559.071700] usb 6-4: Manufacturer: CASIO COMPUTER
[20559.071702] usb 6-4: SerialNumber: 1013651216023336
[20559.072266] usb-storage 6-4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[20559.077593] scsi host4: usb-storage 6-4:1.0
[20560.101966] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     CASIO    DIGITAL_CAMERA   1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[20560.103246] sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[20560.103957] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] 60874752 512-byte logical blocks: (31.2 GB/29.0 GiB)
[20560.104668] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[20560.104671] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 00 46 02 00
[20560.109562] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[20560.109568] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[20560.116609]  sdb: sdb1
[20560.121257] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[20570.863660] usb-storage 6-4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[20570.863979] scsi host4: usb-storage 6-4:1.0
[20602.833249] usb 6-4: reset high-speed USB device number 26 using ehci-pci
[20603.605440] usb 6-4: USB disconnect, device number 26
[20740.257338] usb 6-4: new high-speed USB device number 27 using ehci-pci
[20740.418600] usb 6-4: New USB device found, idVendor=07cf, idProduct=117a, bcdDevice=10.00
[20740.418606] usb 6-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=4
[20740.418609] usb 6-4: Product: CASIO QV DIGITAL
[20740.418612] usb 6-4: Manufacturer: CASIO COMPUTER
[20740.418614] usb 6-4: SerialNumber: 1013651216023336
[20740.420074] usb-storage 6-4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[20740.427342] scsi host4: usb-storage 6-4:1.0
[20741.445843] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     CASIO    DIGITAL_CAMERA   1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[20741.446985] sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[20741.447736] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] 60874752 512-byte logical blocks: (31.2 GB/29.0 GiB)
[20741.448313] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[20741.448315] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 00 46 02 00
[20741.448942] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[20741.448948] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[20741.456965]  sdb: sdb1
[20741.462199] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[20749.783725] usb-storage 6-4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[20749.784035] scsi host4: usb-storage 6-4:1.0
[20781.777274] usb 6-4: reset high-speed USB device number 27 using ehci-pci
[20782.549420] usb 6-4: USB disconnect, device number 27
```

I have tried to insert a udev rule at /etc/udev/rules.d/57-photo.rules containing...

```
KERNEL=="sd?1", SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi", ATTR{idProduct}=="117a", ATTR{idVendor}=="07cf", NAME="Casio EX-ZR700"
```

but nothing has changed. Where is my error ?

Here is the device information...

udevadm info -a -p /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb6/6-4

```
Udevadm info starts with the device specified by the devpath and then
walks up the chain of parent devices. It prints for every device
found, all possible attributes in the udev rules key format.
A rule to match, can be composed by the attributes of the device
and the attributes from one single parent device.

  looking at device '//devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb6/6-4':
    KERNEL=="6-4"
    SUBSYSTEM=="usb"
    DRIVER=="usb"
    ATTR{devnum}=="48"
    ATTR{removable}=="removable"
    ATTR{bDeviceClass}=="00"
    ATTR{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTR{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTR{bmAttributes}=="80"
    ATTR{bDeviceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTR{product}=="CASIO QV DIGITAL"
    ATTR{idVendor}=="07cf"
    ATTR{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTR{serial}=="1013651216023336"
    ATTR{configuration}==""
    ATTR{rx_lanes}=="1"
    ATTR{tx_lanes}=="1"
    ATTR{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTR{authorized}=="1"
    ATTR{urbnum}=="79"
    ATTR{bNumConfigurations}=="2"
    ATTR{idProduct}=="117a"
    ATTR{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTR{bcdDevice}=="1000"
    ATTR{version}==" 2.00"
    ATTR{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTR{bMaxPower}=="500mA"
    ATTR{devpath}=="4"
    ATTR{speed}=="480"
    ATTR{maxchild}=="0"
    ATTR{manufacturer}=="CASIO COMPUTER"
    ATTR{busnum}=="6"
    ATTR{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"

  looking at parent device '//devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb6':
    KERNELS=="usb6"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{product}=="EHCI Host Controller"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="6"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0419"
    ATTRS{interface_authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"
    ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="6"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="0"
    ATTRS{authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="0002"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="1d6b"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{rx_lanes}=="1"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="1538"
    ATTRS{serial}=="0000:00:1d.7"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="0mA"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{tx_lanes}=="1"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Linux 4.19.0-18-amd64 ehci_hcd"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"

  looking at parent device '//devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7':
    KERNELS=="0000:00:1d.7"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="pci"
    DRIVERS=="ehci-pci"
    ATTRS{local_cpulist}=="0-1"
    ATTRS{class}=="0x0c0320"
    ATTRS{revision}=="0x03"
    ATTRS{consistent_dma_mask_bits}=="32"
    ATTRS{uframe_periodic_max}=="100"
    ATTRS{d3cold_allowed}=="1"
    ATTRS{irq}=="23"
    ATTRS{ari_enabled}=="0"
    ATTRS{msi_bus}=="1"
    ATTRS{vendor}=="0x8086"
    ATTRS{dma_mask_bits}=="32"
    ATTRS{numa_node}=="-1"
    ATTRS{enable}=="1"
    ATTRS{broken_parity_status}=="0"
    ATTRS{local_cpus}=="3"
    ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x1043"
    ATTRS{companion}==""
    ATTRS{driver_override}=="(null)"
    ATTRS{device}=="0x293a"
    ATTRS{subsystem_device}=="0x1867"

  looking at parent device '//devices/pci0000:00':
    KERNELS=="pci0000:00"
    SUBSYSTEMS==""
    DRIVERS==""
```

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

Your device is detected **twice** (once at 20559, once 10 seconds later, with no error messages or detach messages in between). I'd assume this leads to trouble, which then causes the reset, which causes the cycle.

So the question is to find out what is misconfigured on your system so you get two detections. Remote debugging is difficult to do with the Q&A on this site, but you can restart `udevd` manually with `udevd --debug-trace --verbose` to potentially get an idea what is going on.

---

Extract from log:

```
Oct 20 14:05:24 defi systemd-udevd[267]: target4:0:0: Device (SEQNUM=3294, ACTION=add) is queued
Oct 20 14:05:24 defi systemd-udevd[267]: 4:0:0:0: Device (SEQNUM=3295, ACTION=add) is queued
Oct 20 14:05:24 defi systemd-udevd[267]: 4:0:0:0: Device (SEQNUM=3296, ACTION=add) is queued
Oct 20 14:05:24 defi systemd-udevd[267]: 4:0:0:0: Device (SEQNUM=3297, ACTION=bind) is queued
Oct 20 14:05:24 defi systemd-udevd[267]: 4:0:0:0: Device (SEQNUM=3298, ACTION=add) is queued
Oct 20 14:05:24 defi systemd-udevd[267]: sg2: Device (SEQNUM=3299, ACTION=add) is queued
Oct 20 14:05:24 defi kernel: scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     CASIO    DIGITAL_CAMERA   1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
Oct 20 14:05:24 defi kernel: sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
Oct 20 14:05:24 defi systemd-udevd[267]: 4:0:0:0: Device (SEQNUM=3300, ACTION=add) is queued
Oct 20 14:05:24 defi kernel: sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] 60874752 512-byte logical blocks: (31.2 GB/29.0 GiB)
Oct 20 14:05:24 defi kernel: sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
Oct 20 14:05:24 defi kernel: sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 00 46 02 00
Oct 20 14:05:24 defi kernel: sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
Oct 20 14:05:24 defi kernel: sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
Oct 20 14:05:24 defi systemd-udevd[267]: 8:16: Device (SEQNUM=3301, ACTION=add) is queued
Oct 20 14:05:24 defi systemd-udevd[267]: Successfully forked off 'n/a' as PID 2992.
Oct 20 14:05:24 defi systemd-udevd[267]: 8:16: Worker [2992] is forked for processing SEQNUM=3301.
Oct 20 14:05:24 defi systemd-udevd[2992]: 8:16: Processing device (SEQNUM=3301, ACTION=add)
Oct 20 14:05:24 defi systemd-udevd[2992]: 8:16: Device (SEQNUM=3301, ACTION=add) processed
Oct 20 14:05:24 defi systemd-udevd[2992]: 8:16: sd-device-monitor: Passed 140 byte to netlink monitor
Oct 20 14:05:24 defi kernel:  sdb: sdb1
Oct 20 14:05:24 defi systemd-udevd[267]: sdb: Device (SEQNUM=3302, ACTION=add) is queued
Oct 20 14:05:24 defi systemd-udevd[267]: sdb1: Device (SEQNUM=3303, ACTION=add) is queued
Oct 20 14:05:24 defi kernel: sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
Oct 20 14:05:24 defi systemd-udevd[1721]: Process 'lmt-udev force' succeeded.
Oct 20 14:05:24 defi systemd-udevd[1721]: 6-4: Device (SEQNUM=3288, ACTION=add) processed
Oct 20 14:05:24 defi systemd-udevd[1721]: 6-4: sd-device-monitor: Passed 844 byte to netlink monitor
Oct 20 14:05:24 defi systemd-udevd[267]: 6-4:1.0: sd-device-monitor: Passed 295 byte to netlink monitor
Oct 20 14:05:24 defi systemd-udevd[2992]: 6-4:1.0: Processing device (SEQNUM=3289, ACTION=add)
Oct 20 14:05:24 defi systemd-udevd[2992]: 6-4:1.0: IMPORT builtin 'hwdb' /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules:14
Oct 20 14:05:24 defi systemd-udevd[2992]: 6-4:1.0: IMPORT builtin 'usb_id' /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-libgphoto2-6.rules:9
Oct 20 14:05:24 defi systemd-udevd[2992]: 6-4:1.0: Failed to access usb_interface: No such file or directory
Oct 20 14:05:24 defi systemd-udevd[2992]: 6-4:1.0: IMPORT builtin 'usb_id' fails: No such file or directory
Oct 20 14:05:24 defi systemd-udevd[2992]: 6-4:1.0: RUN 'kmod load $env{MODALIAS}' /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/80-drivers.rules:5
Oct 20 14:05:24 defi systemd-udevd[2992]: 6-4:1.0: RUN 'lmt-udev force' /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/99-laptop-mode.rules:3
Oct 20 14:05:24 defi systemd-udevd[2992]: 6-4:1.0: sd-device: Created db file '/run/udev/data/+usb:6-4:1.0' for '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb6/6-4/6-4:1.0'
Oct 20 14:05:24 defi systemd-udevd[2992]: Loading module: usb:v07CFp117Ad1000dc00dsc00dp00ic08isc05ip50in00
Oct 20 14:05:24 defi systemd-udevd[2992]: Module 'usb_storage' is already loaded
Oct 20 14:05:24 defi systemd-udevd[2992]: Starting 'lmt-udev force'
Oct 20 14:05:24 defi systemd-udevd[2992]: Successfully forked off '(spawn)' as PID 3275.
Oct 20 14:05:24 defi systemd-udevd[267]: 4:0:0:0: Device (SEQNUM=3304, ACTION=remove) is queued
Oct 20 14:05:24 defi systemd-udevd[267]: sg2: Device (SEQNUM=3305, ACTION=remove) is queued
```

So you can see the attaching works correctly, and then at the end of the log extract it decides to remove the device again. The only thing I can see before that is that `usb_id` fails because `usb_interface` was not available, and then it starts reloading modules. Possibly this triggers the removal.

File a bug with the udev developers and see if they have any idea what is happening here.

Comment: On this system, there is only systemd-udevd installed. According to the man pages, the arguments are different.

Comment: I have here the output of the "udevadm monitor" command, but it's to long to insert it here. What can I do ?

Comment: You can put the output in a pastebin (google), and edit your question with a link to the pastebin. Add some information what you have done (e.g. "attached camera, waited 60 seconds, remove camera, waited 60 seconds, attached it again).

Comment: I'm not on google. You will find the compressed log extract here: https://dj0ot.darc.de/Xtract.bz2

Comment: I meant "google (search) for a pastebin", e.g. https://pastebin.com (there are lots of others). I am not "on" Google either.